# punctuation: the 20 to 30 year old age group

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, hyphenation, numbers, dashes

I'd like to know how "the 20 to 30 year old age group" is punctuated in standard English.
"30-year-old" should be hyphenated. What about "20 to 30"?

Any principles at work?

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: There is no single answer to this. I would *personally* replace *20 to 30* with an en dash, turning this into *the 20–30-year-old age group*. (Or you could rephrase it altogether: *The group of people aged 20 to 30.*)

Comment: I would write “the 20- to 30-year-old age group” (but I don’t have an authoritative source for this).

Comment: @MitchellSpector I've noticed you put a space between "20-" and "to" in your version. I'm wondering why no such space exists in "a nine-to-five job."

Comment: Yes, the space was intentional. I’ve always understood “20- to 30-year-old” to be a shortened version of “20-year-old to 30-year-old.”

Comment: “Nine-to-five job” is different. It’s not short for “nine-job to five-job.”

Comment: @MitchellSpector That punctuation would make sense if it were *the 20- **and** 30-year-old age* ***groups***. When you collapse hyphenation in that way, it's because it's a shortened version of something longer (*the 20-year-old age group **and** the 30-year-old age group*). But, in this case, it's a range of numbers that apply to a *single* age group, not two different age groups, each with their own hyphenation but joined by a conjunction. An alternative, which I didn't give in my original comment, is to close everything: *the 20-to-30-year-old age group*.